# Adding a JButton to a JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

I am trying to learn how to use JFrames. I have a JFrame, that has a JPanel, that has a JButton. I add the JButton to the JPanel, which is added to the JFrame. My code is below, I cannot figure out why this won't work. It should not matter if I do not have a layout set correct? I'm just trying to figure this out to help me solve a larger problem using layouts, any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
public class one {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        f.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JButton b = new JButton("Testing");
        b.setBounds(60, 60, 100, 100);
        b.setVisible(true);



        p.add(b);

        f.add(p);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Instead running this code only opens a blank JFrame.

Comment: Why do you explicitly set the `JFrame`'s layout manager to `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `JPanel` contains all the `Component`s you should set the `JPanel` as `ContentPane` for the `JFrame`.

So you need to change this

```
f.add(p);
```

to

```
f.setContentPane(p);
```

If the `JPanel` is just for specific `Component`s you should set bounds for the `JPanel` and add it.

Example for `BorderLayout`:

```
f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```